# Getting the ids of multiple inserted hasMany items in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-many, saving-data

**Description / Explanation:**

On the "Add an Event" page, you can add multiple Schedules.  When you saveAll(), it saves the Event data and all the Schedule(s) data - this is working correctly.

But THEN, I want to process the schedule(s) data and build individual rows in the "dates" table.

```
Event hasMany Schedule
Schedule belongsTo Event
Schedule hasMany Date
Date belongsTo Schedule
```

So - I'm loading the Date model, and repeating through each Schedule that was passed, and processing/inserting the dates (based on repeat, start date...etc etc).

**My problem / Question:**

I need the id of each schedule for it's Dates ("schedule_id" field).  How do I get the id's of individual Schedules during the repeat?  Currently, I'm doing this:

```
foreach($this->data['Schedule'] as $i => $value) {
    $this->data['Date']['schedule_id'] = $this->Event->Schedule->id;
    //other stuff here
    $this->Date->saveAll($this->data['Date']);
}
```

But that gives me the same id in every loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `$this->Event->Schedule->id` only holds the LAST id of an insert. This is why you always get the same id.

I suppose you are doing this foreach loop within your add-function of your Events-controller.
If you want each own insert-id you shouldn't do a saveAll on your Event and rather loop through each Schedule (as you already do) and save the schedules there. This could look like this:

```
foreach ($this->data['Schedule'] as $schedule) {
    $schedule['event_id'] = $this->Event->id; //this is needed because we don't do a saveAll on the Event anymore
    $this->Event->Schedule->save($schedule);

    //Here comes your part
    $this->data['Date']['schedule_id'] = $this->Event->Schedule->id;
    //other stuff here
    $this->Event->Schedule->Date->saveAll($this->data['Date']);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it does help, thank you.  The only problem with this is, it won't validate them together like saveAll() does.  Is there a way to validate them all first, THEN do this type of saving?  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I believe I answered my own question - you can manually validate - information here:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1182/Validating-Data-from-the-Controller